# Validação de CPF

Tags: javascript, jquery

estava fazendo validador de CPF em Js e queria saber como posso verificar se ele realmente é de uma pessoa existente e não apenas pelo padrão do cálculo feito:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lucaskazama/t5fhwn23/

Comment: Acredito que para você saber isso tem que consumir algo com a Receita Federal.

Comment: Tem de usar esse serviço de um banco de dados com CPF's verificados.

Comment: No caso, somente o da Receita Federal tem isso, certo?
Estava pesquisando e vi que usam Webservice para isso mas a maioria cobram pela consulta, sabe dizer se existe algum gratuito?

Comment: Use esse site: https://www.geradorcpf.com/validar-cpf.htm?

Comment: @DavisRoberto A validação é pelo cálculo, assim como no meu Js...
https://jsfiddle.net/Lucaskazama/t5fhwn23/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se você está desenvolvendo um sistema incapaz de lidar com CPFs válidos porém inexistentes, a única maneira confiável é consultar a fonte deles em um órgão competente (como a Receita Federal, citada nos comentários).

Caso você não considere a possibilidade de consumir um serviço pago, sugiro rever os requisitos da aplicação. Acredito que não existam serviços gratuitos para atender a sua necessidade; e, como você não especificou o tipo de ferramenta que está desenvolvendo, arrisco dizer que uma validação de documentos pode ser suficiente.

Se necessário, atualize sua pergunta adicionado mais detalhes sobre a necessidade e tentaremos ajudar de maneira mais específica.

Comment: O que eu acho estranho é que podemos consultar gratuitamente  as informações contidas no CPF tendo o CPF e data de nascimento no site da Receita Federal, mas não tem nenhuma api ou webservice disso gratuita :/

Comment: Desconheço os motivos para essa limitação, mas considero, de certa maneira, a privacidade como um dos fatores. Com uma API pública gratuita (ou até mesmo um site sem a validação do reCAPTCHA) seria tecnicamente viável de fazer ataques de força bruta e obter informações em massa. A utilização incorreta desses dados pode trazer impactos negativos à segurança das pessoas. Mas isso é apenas um dos pontos, já que existem outros meios - possivelmente ilegais - de obter essas informações.